# how to use case with group by?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case, where-clause

the query  works well but when iam adding group by it gives me  [Error]  ORA-01427 here is the main query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Contract_number,
              area_number,
              area_name,
              ADVANCE_PAY,
              Postponed_Amount,
              extract_number,
              total
FROM (SELECT xxr.Contract_num Contract_number,
             xxr.p_area_no area_number,
             xxr.p_area_name area_name,
             xxr.ADVANCE_PAY ADVANCE_PAY,
             xxr.DEFERRED_BOOST Postponed_Amount,
             xxr.release_num extract_number,
```

and here is the case statement :

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT
                     CASE
                        WHEN :p_item_code IS NOT NULL
                        THEN
                           TOTAL_AMOUNT
                        WHEN :p_item_code IS NULL
                        THEN
                           ( (SELECT NVL (SUM (TOTAL_AMOUNT), 0)
                                FROM XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES
                               WHERE XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES.release_id =
                                        XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES.release_id))
                        ELSE
                           NULL
                     END
                FROM XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES xxrl,
                     XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
               WHERE     1 = 1
                     AND xxrl.release_id =
                            XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES.release_id)
                AS total
```

and here is the from part :

```
  FROM XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES xxrl,
             XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES xxr
       WHERE 1 = 1 
       AND xxrl.release_id = xxr.release_id
       AND xxr.release_date >= NVL (:p_date_from, xxr.release_date)
             AND xxr.release_date <= NVL (:p_date_to, xxr.release_date)
             AND xxr.Contract_num = NVL (:p_cont_num, xxr.Contract_num)
             AND xxr.vendor_id = NVL (:p_ven_id, xxr.vendor_id)
             AND xxr.vendor_site_id = NVL (:p_site_id, xxr.vendor_site_id)

            )
```

and here is the group by :

```
GROUP BY Contract_number,
     area_number,
     area_name,
     ADVANCE_PAY,
     Postponed_Amount,
     extract_number,
     total;
```

these is the full query so please any help

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Show the full query, not only parts. Btw, both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` do the same, son only one of them is needed.

Comment: i want to get the total amount if the user entered a specific parameter (total amount is a column name  )  and get the sum of the total amount  if the user dosent  enter any parameter

Comment: @dnoeth i've trayed to use group by only and it gave me the same error

Comment: i dont konw why they voted negative for my question there is no one who can gives me a helpful answer ?!!!

Comment: as you said you got the error ORA-01427 that means your subquery result returning more than one row. i.e. your case statement it should retrun only one row

Comment: @HemantDhake so why when i remove the alias of the case statement from the group by it works ?!

Comment: @Tarek you mean just removing "AS total" it works?

Comment: @HemantD  no when i removing total from the group by it works well but i dosnt retrieve the case condition  !!

Comment: Tarek just a hint mate, and believe me I speak from experience, break down your problem into a small problem with some sample data that the folks here can easily use to recreate your query and your end result. The way you proposed the question leaves it all up to us to try and figuered out what you are trying to acomplish. Put up a table ddl, some sample data and a expected result along with what you tried and I'm sure you will get an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

For sure I couldn't understand very well your query. You could improve your post for next time.

As answer, I think you should encapsulate your select statment and group by using your select as subquery. It is not the best approach but it may works fine.

```
select *
from (
    select distinct Contract_number
        ,area_number
        ,area_name
        ,ADVANCE_PAY
        ,Postponed_Amount
        ,extract_number
        ,total
    from (
        select xxr.Contract_num Contract_number
            ,xxr.p_area_no area_number
            ,xxr.p_area_name area_name
            ,xxr.ADVANCE_PAY ADVANCE_PAY
            ,xxr.DEFERRED_BOOST Postponed_Amount
            ,xxr.release_num extract_number
            ,(
                select distinct case 
                        when :p_item_code is not null
                            then TOTAL_AMOUNT
                        when :p_item_code is null
                            then (
                                    (
                                        select NVL(SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT), 0)
                                        from XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES
                                        where XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES.release_id = XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES.release_id
                                        )
                                    )
                        else null
                        end
                from XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES xxrl
                    ,XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
                where 1 = 1
                    and xxrl.release_id = XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES.release_id
                ) as total
        from XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES_LINES xxrl
            ,XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES xxr
        where 1 = 1
            and xxrl.release_id = xxr.release_id
            and xxr.release_date >= NVL(:p_date_from, xxr.release_date)
            and xxr.release_date <= NVL(:p_date_to, xxr.release_date)
            and xxr.Contract_num = NVL(:p_cont_num, xxr.Contract_num)
            and xxr.vendor_id = NVL(:p_ven_id, xxr.vendor_id)
            and xxr.vendor_site_id = NVL(:p_site_id, xxr.vendor_site_id)
        )
    ) TBL1
group by TBL1.Contract_number
    ,TBL1.area_number
    ,TBL1.area_name
    ,TBL1.ADVANCE_PAY
    ,TBL1.Postponed_Amount
    ,TBL1.extract_number
    ,TBL1.total;
```